# Limit redis connections when using PhpRedis as session store

Tags: php, apache-2.4, redis, session

We are using [PhpRedis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler) as a session handler for PHP sessions. Other than that, we are running a standard Apache/PHP configuration.

Since we are using an external Redis-as-a-service provider, we would like to keep the number of connections low as they dictate the monthly payment.

We are experiencing ever growing number of connections, even at times when the PHP site is completely idle. Connection count is always on the rise and we reach dozens of connections quickly.

Is there a way to limit / pool these connections?

The only probably related solution we found, is to limit the number of workers Apache spawns, but it seems to me like a too harsh of a solution.

We have already tried using `persistent=1` in the connection string without any visible change.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Use a redis proxy such as... [redis-proxy](https://github.com/sreeix/redis-proxy).

Comment: Thanks. Would prefer not adding another dependency.

Comment: Well, then, you can pay the service provider whatever they're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually proxy your Redis connections through a tool like [twmproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) or [redis-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-proxy). The proxy will maintain the connections persistently and can queue, route, and limit connections to the Redis servers.

This configuration can also help with issues of High Availability and Load Balancing.